# How to write integral

Tags: integration, notation

When solving a integral problem domain $[x_1,x_2]$, I start with writing down this:
$$\int_{x_1}^{x_2} f(x) dx = F(x_2) - F(x_1).$$
Then I calculate the $F(x)$ and fill in the respected $x_1$ and $x_2$.

But when the function in the problem given starts already is capitalized: $T(x) = 2x$.
How do I write down the integral function?
$$\int_{x_1}^{x_2} T(x) dx = T(x_2) - T(x_1),$$ 
simply looks stupid.

Isn't there an similar symbol like the one used for the derivative, the apostrophe ( ' )?

Any ideas?

Comment: The way to write an integral is by using [MathJax](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) :)

Comment: $$\int_{x_1}^{x_2} T'(x)\ dx=T(x_2)-T(x_1)$$

Comment: @SimplyBeautifulArt The function being integrated is called $T$. OP wants a notation for the antiderivative of $T$.

Comment: Just saying, you could try calling it $T'$ instead, or maybe $f'(x)$.

Answer (score 4):

I'd write "$\int_a^b T(x)~ dx = U(b) - U(a)$, where $U$ is any antiderviative of $T$."

In fact, in what you've proposed as your "standard" method, it'd probably be a good idea to mention that "$F$ is an antiderivative of $f$" as well, and not rely on other folks heaving learned the same typographical conventions as those used by your teacher or textbook author.

Comment: +1 for the explicit recommendation to separate the actual mathematics from the typographic convention.